# Spring & Hibernate JPA TypedQuery: how to handle IN clause when the value & its type it is given dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am building a REST API with Spring boot & Hibernate. The idea is that the API can be queried dynamically for all its entities with a GraphQL-like request. Heres a quick example how the API request object might look like:

```
"filter": {
    "and": [
        { 
            "id": { "in": [1, 2, 3] },
            "name": { "eq": "example name" }
        }
    ]
}
```

Inside the "and"-array there are objects that basically contain the key as the entity's field to use in the filter and then another object that tells the operator and values to use during the query, in this case equals and IN operators. The important part here is that as you can see, the value is dynamic. In the example there is an array and a string.

I build a JPQL-query from the request object and if we think that we do NOT include the equals filter but only the in filter with the values `[1, 2, 3]` for the next example, it constructs the following JPQL:

`SELECT t FROM Entity t WHERE id IN :id1`

The IN filter is stored in a map with a string key and an object as a value because the value can be dynamic depending on the filter: `Map<String, Object> filters;`

After everythings set I create a `TypedQuery` as follows:

```
TypedQuery<T> query = entityManager.createQuery(queryData.getFirst(), clazz);
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : queryData.getSecond().entrySet()) {
    query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Whereas the queryData.getFirst() returns the JPQL as seen above, and the queryData.getSecond() contains filters key & value that is set to the JPQL. In this case id1 and the [1, 2, 3] values for the JPQL.

When i have created and set the parameters for the TypedQuery and try to get the results with either `query.getResultStream()` or `query.getResultList()` I get a `ClassCastException` like so:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Long are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LongJavaType.unwrap(LongJavaType.java:24) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BigIntJdbcType$1.doBind(BigIntJdbcType.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.AbstractJdbcParameter.bindParameterValue(AbstractJdbcParameter.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.AbstractJdbcParameter.bindParameterValue(AbstractJdbcParameter.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.ScrollableResultsIterator.hasNext(ScrollableResultsIterator.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:132)
```

I understand that the issue is when the IN values are given as an Object, Java detects it's value as `List<Integer>` that is set to the query as so, but since the actual id field of the entity is a type of `Long` it fails somewhere. The IN filter works if i query entity's field that is a type of String when the values are set accordingly like `["first", "second"]` but I can't seem to figure out how to work out the problem with different value types.

Any suggestions how I could maybe detect the type of the entity's field and then maybe try casting the values accordingly or anything else that might help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that utilizing a static query might not be the best fit for your current scenario. Instead, I recommend leveraging the `CriteriaAPI`, a flexible approach in Hibernate/JPA for crafting dynamic queries.

Let's assume you intend to search for `User` entities using this approach:

```java
List<FilterCondition> and = List.of(
    new FilterCondition("id", "in", List.of(1, 2, 3)),
    new FilterCondition("name", "eq", "example name"));

Filter filter = new Filter(and);

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> root = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

for (FilterCondition condition : filter.getAnd()) {
    String fieldName = condition.getField();
    Path<?> path = root.get(fieldName);
    
    if ("in".equals(condition.getOperator())) {
        List<?> values = (List<?>) condition.getValue();
        predicates.add(path.in(values));
    } else if ("eq".equals(condition.getOperator())) {
        Object value = condition.getValue();
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(path, value));
    }
}

criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
List<User> users = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

This approach is especially useful for building complex queries based on various filter conditions.